# Echo'ing ob_start callback in external PHP file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, ob-start

I'm working on population static `HTML` with database information in `PHP`. The `HTML` files have a pattern ({{$pattern}}) which when located in an `HTML` file will be replaced with a matching `PHP` variable. 
An example `HTML` file could be:

```
<div>{{$apples}}</div>
```

To populate this `HTML` file on demand, I've created the following `PHP` script (`prepend.inc`):

```
function ob_callback($buffer){

    global $data;
    $data['apples'] = CONSTANT; //global definition defined elsewhere

    $buffer = preg_replace_callback(
          '/{{\$([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)}}/',
          function($matches){
                 global $data;
             return (isset($data[$matches[1]])?$data[$matches[1]]:"");
          },
          $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
ob_start("ob_callback");
```

This scrip is prepended to every `HTML` file by adding the following to the `.htaccess` in the `HTML` directory:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepend.inc"
```

Because of the architecture of my application, I require an `HTML` file echo'ed in `PHP`.
 This has however proven to be a bigger task than expected because any attempt I make at converting the file to a `PHP` string and echo'ing results in the above `ob_callback` not being executed... (Althrough I know `prepend.inc` is run)
I have tried `fread`, `file_get_content` and even:

```
const CONSTANT = 'oranges';
ob_start();
require 'theHTMLfile.html';
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $out;
```

None of these however seem to have reached the ob_start callback in prepend.inc, and have had the pattern replaced...
One solution would be to use the full URL (`require 'http://www.example.com/theHTMLfile.html';`), but I CANNOT use that as it would break the reference to global variables, that I require to fetch data for the `HTML` etc..

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: `$data` in your callback above is a local variable

Comment: Sure, actually the supplied code is a simplification to avoid straying from the point. I'm however looking for a solution assuming `$data` represents a global variable..

Comment: Then you should post the real code, because in the one you posted `$data` is not declared as global, so the global variable you are trying to access in the pcre callback function is empty

Comment: Anyway thats besides the point, my question is, if there exists a workaround for the fact that `ob_callback` never fires when I include the `HTML` file with a relative and not absolute path?

Comment: Yes, the relative path may not resolve. Did you try with the actual absolute path to the file (not the URL) ?

Comment: Yeah that didn't resolve it either, only the full URL...